# Replace strings from different files according to condition

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am new in Python coding and I got a problem concerning csv file data manipulation.

Basically, I have 2 csv file that I import thanks to pd.read_csv they look like

[df1 which has 9 rows including headers and 5 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns2aj.jpg)

[df2 which has 65 rows including headers and same 5 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeWqd.jpg)

I want to replace sentences in df1 by sentences in df2 in respect to the `'NBIMAGE'` and save a third csv called `df3` (or just save a modified version of df1 as df1 without a new file)

*In other words whenever'NBIMAGE'in df1 = 'NBIMAGE' in df2 (even if rows are different) it should replace the SENTENCE of that row in df1 by the sentence with the same 'NBIMAGE' in df2*

what I have done is

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

df1['newcolumn'] = 
np.where (df1['NBIMAGE'] == df2['NBIMAGE'], df2['SENTENCE'], 0)
```

but it outputs an 
`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

I don't want to use replace since I we need to specify by what to replace but I think use of numpy for strings is not the best solution neither....

I hope you understood my problem and want to thank you all for you help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df3 = df1.drop('SENTENCE',axis=1).merge(df2[['NBIMAGE','SENTENCE']],how='left', on='NBIMAGE')
```